# Click event not triggering alert

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to trigger this alert on click of `.ss-result a` and on blur of `input`. When both of those events happen.

On focus of the input, the anchor appears. Then when one clicks the anchor the click event should be registered and since the focus is taken off of the input, the blur even, on the input, should be registered.

So, why isn' this alert running then.

On click, isn't the focus transferred from the  to `.ss-result a`? So when on clicks on the anchor, the alert should fire, right?

What I am trying to do is to know when a blur event happens on `input` and if the focus was transferred to `.ss-result a` due to it being clicked. How can I run javascript, in this case an alert, in that event?

Here is my code:

```
$('.ss-result').fadeOut();

$('input').focus(function(){
    $('.ss-result').fadeIn();
});
var inputObj = $('input');
var boxObj = $('.ss-result');
inputObj.blur(function() {
    if($('.ss-result a').is(':focus')){
        alert("clicked!");
}
else{
    boxObj.fadeOut(100);
}
});
```

And here is a JS FIDDLE where you can try it out: http://jsfiddle.net/CtcB8/

Comment: It can't be focused if is onblur...

Comment: This is the third time I've seen this question roll through.

Answer (score 1):

It can't be both, so you could just do

```
inputObj.blur(function() {
        alert("clicked!");
});
```

and respond to the click event.

EDIT: Thanks to @Igor for pointing out the unnecessary bit.

Comment: will `$('.ss-result a')` ever resolve to `false`?

Comment: Nope. It's not needed at all. Just being lazy.

Comment: How do I respond to the click event? Just listen for it inside?

Comment: Yes - listen to the click event on `.ss-result a`. See for example http://jsfiddle.net/CtcB8/1/